# How to call function when clicked outside an element and avoid firing click inside click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have folders on my page with class '**.folder-ico**'. When I click on some folder, the tiny menu inside this folder appears by calling function **addTinyMenuInsideIco()**. Now If I click any element except clicked folder or clicked folder's elements tiny menu should be removed by using **removeTinnyMenuInsideIco()**. Unfortunately, **$('body').on('click',function(e){}**... fires automatically after clicking on folder. Any tips how to do it properly?

```
<div class="folder-ico">
    <div class="folder-image">
    <h2>Ico 1</h2>
</div>

<div class="folder-ico">
    <div class="folder-image">
    <h2>Ico 2</h2>
</div>

<!-- ... -->

<div class="folder-ico">
    <div class="folder-image">
    <h2>Ico n</h2>
</div>

<script>

$('.folder-ico').on('click', whenClickOnIco);

function whenClickOnIco ()
{
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked'))
    {
        // Add class '.clicked'
        $(this).addClass('clicked');

        // Add tiny menu inside ico.
        addTinyMenuInsideIco();

        // Remember 'old this'
        let tempThis = this;

        // Add click event to all body elements.
        $('body').on('click',function(e)
        {
            // Clicked on some body element except class '.clicked'.
            if(!$(e.target).hasClass('clicked'))
            {
                // Remove class '.clicked'.
                $(tempThis).removeClass('clicked');

                // Remove tiny menu inside ico.
                removeTinnyMenuInsideIco();

                // Unbind click event.
                $('body').unbind('click');

                // Add event click to unbinded elements.
                $('.folder-ico').on('click', whenClickOnIco);
            }
        })
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your event call:
`event.preventDefault();`

or you can prevent nested elements from firing the parent element's event by adding
`event.stopPropagation();`

[MDN preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

[MDN stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: `preventDefault()` isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is called **Bubbling** (I'm suggesting you to read [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)).

The idea's outlines is: when an event is fired inside an inner element, the event is fired first into the element, then, by order, is *bubbled up* into the parent elements.

Most of the time this is powerful. For example, if I have a button with an image inside, I want a click on the image to trigger the button's click event listeners. Unfortunately, sometimes, like in your case, you don't want that. Fortunately, there is a solution.

As you might know, each event listener in js has an `event` parameter. This parameter has a method called `stopPropagation()`, which stops the bubbling. So, what you need to do is the following:

```js
function whenClickOnIco (e)
{
  e.stopPropagation();
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I should learn about Bubbling, but adding e.stopPropagaton() to whenClickOnIco() doesn't work. Anyway is it a good solution to put click inside click in my case? Maybe there is another way to do it?

Comment: @Tomasz Show your full code with stopPropagation().

Comment: @Tomasz And there is a easier way to do one-time event in jquery, using `once()` instead of `on()`.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tomas_code/uksvz95a/1/) here you go. If you press longer on the folder the tiny menu activates. I added **e.stopPropagation();** at the be begining of the **tapLongPress(e)** function. Try to uncomment **('body').on('click',function(e)** and run. PS: I've also noticed that after longer pressing and releasing the mouse whenClickOnCatFolder fires and add .selected-folder-cat class which is not good...